# How to convert datetime to UTC in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory to copying data from a delimited text file on our SFTP to a SQL database on Azure.  Everything works correctly.  However, recently, we found that we need to convert a datetime column (IntervalTime) from Central Time Zone to UTC using function '@convertToUtc()'.  However, I am not sure where you put the conversion.  Can explain how to do this?  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be achieved in Copy data activity due to it doesn't support transforming column value.

There are serval workarounds:

1. copy data from sftp to connectors which is supported as source in Data Flow. And convert IntervalTime to UTC in Data FLOW by using [toUTC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#toutc) function.
2. use Lookup activity to get data from SFTP and create a SP to convert IntervalTime in Azure SQL Database. Then invoke the SP in ADF. Note that the Lookup activity has a maximum of 5,000 rows, and a maximum size of 4 MB.
3. create a trigger in Azure SQL Database and convert IntervalTime to UTC in it.